# PHP 5.5 and POP3

Tags: php, imap, pop3

Is there a current working POP3 extension for PHP or a way to install one? I tried PELC and failed to install and I looked it up and the last update was back in 2004 or so with PHP 4.

Is the prebuilt IMAP flag when you compile PHP the same thing?

Comment: what are you looking to do?

Comment: The imap extension will handle POP3 mailboxes too. See the manual for [imap_open()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php)

Comment: Check out this comment for a starting point, though I would OOP-ify the code and make it a bit more flexible: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php#96414